# How to start to create a Video renderer for pjsip on Android as Csipsimple

Tags: android, android-ndk, video-streaming, sip, pjsip

I wanna to create my own video renderer on Android because the pjsip doesn't provide a video renderer for Android. I don't know where to start. Which pjsip function should I override.

I know that `CSipsimple` solution got a video renderer which I assume resides in the Video Plugin which is a compiled .so file ..no source code..So any suggestions about where to start. I never handled with `OpenGl` or Android NDK.

So please provide a simple explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are incorrect, csipsimple does provide the source:

They use the [webrtc API](http://simonguest.com/2013/08/06/building-a-webrtc-client-for-android/) to get the [camera feed](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/source/browse/trunk/CSipSimple#CSipSimple/jni/webrtc/pj_sources%253Fstate%253Dclosed) and [display](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/source/browse/trunk/CSipSimple#CSipSimple/src/org/webrtc/videoengine%253Fstate%253Dclosed).